# Jetpack Compose any ability to change text overflow on the single line TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

If the user inputs more text than can fit into the available space of a single line TextField, then the end of the text is simply cropped.

Unlike the Text widget, however, the TextField does not have an overflow parameter so we can for example show an ellipsis in this situation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.